# Django - Accessing Foreign Key values to save to dictionary

Tags: django, django-models

In Django, I would like to create a dictionary from model values which also include the Foreign Key values.

So, for example, I have 2 models:

--models.py--

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    item_description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Inventory(models.Model):
    inventory_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    inventory_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    inventory_item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

(not the best variable name examples since it could be a many to many relationship, but you get the point)

In my urls, I need a path that shows the primary key because I will have some other functions based their pks from the URL.

--urls.py--

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('details/<int:pk>/', views.GenerateDetails, name='details'),
]
```

Now, here's were I'm having issues.

I'm trying to create a dictionary from the Inventory model that will also have the ForeignKey values from Item.

--views.py--

```
class GenerateDetails(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        inventory_data = Inventory.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))

        # Create dictionary from selected contract_data
        inventory_data_dict = model_to_dict(inventory_data)

        ...

        return response
```

From this solution, the only ForeingKey value that the dictionary saves is Item__id and that's it.

I would like the dictionary to save all the data for Inventory as well as Item__name and Item__description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Inventory.objects.filter(self.kwargs.get('pk')).values('inventory_name', 'inventory_date', 'inventory_item__item_name', 'inventory_item__ item_description').first()
```

And I suggest you to use shorter name for fields like name instead of item_name and item_description, and just use item not inventory item, you already know that item is FK for inventory

Comment: after I added the id variable on the .filter(), it worked! thank you!


Inventory.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs.get('pk')).values('inventory_name', 'inventory_date', 'inventory_item__item_name', 'inventory_item__ item_description').first()